# How do I access docker from mac command line?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, terminal, dockerfile

I am following a tutorial to learn docker and in the video the person says to access docker from the command line and then run `docker ps` . I tried doing that through my mac terminal and got an error saying `/bin/sh: docker: not found` .

Here is the code in my terminal:

`Last login: Tue Aug 17 11:42:10 on ttys000 docker exec -it 41287e54390daa5016ed1f778022d05ae984ed27f62344c542d0662aee4d2230  /bin/sh nila@Nilas-MacBook-Air ~ % docker exec -it 41287e54390daa5016ed1f778022d05ae984ed27f62344c542d0662aee4d2230 /bin/sh / # docker ps /bin/sh: docker: not found`

In the tutorial this is how it looks when you run `docker ps`:
[tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIB2f.png)

Here is the link to the tutorial I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAkwW2tuIqE

Comment: Did you install `Docker Desktop` on your machine? And if you already did, open up a new terminal and run the docker commands.

Comment: Are you trying to run `docker`  commands inside a container? It is not clear

Comment: @ErangaHeshan yes I have installed Docker Desktop, what docker commands do you want me to run? The docker ps? I am sorry I am new to this so I have no idea

Comment: @KrishanThisera no I am trying to run the docker ps to get a list of containers.

Comment: I meant you need to run the commands in a brand new terminal. If you install the Docker Desktop and try to run any Docker command in an old terminal, that terminal might not have updated with Docker commands. Just try to open a new terminal and tun any Docker command. If it still does not work, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Docker Desktop and the application appears in applications, then open a new terminal window and type `docker -version` and you should receive output relating to the version of docker.

More information can be found on the Docker documentation,

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/